# How to undo the header and footer created with pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, header-footer

I created pdf header and footer with following commands

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[a4paper,top=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\fancyfoot[RO]{\url{https://exmple.com}}
\fancyfoot[LO]{\url{https://exmple.com}}
\fancyfoot[CO]{\thepage}

\fancyhead[LO]{\url{https://exmple.com}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\url{https://exmple.com}}

 
  
  \includepdf[pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}},pages=2-]{test.pdf}

\end{document}
```

I need to undo the operation. How to do it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What exactly want you to undo? If you do not want an footer, do not load `fancyhdr` and comment `\fancyfoot` and `\fancyhead` ...

Comment: Hello I need to remove header and footer created with above code. I don't have pdf without header and footer to try another test

Comment: it removes hyperlinks only

Comment: Replacee `\thispagestyle{fancy}` with `\thispagestyle{empty}` in `\includepdf`.  Also, check the order of package loading.  hyperraf likes to go last, but some packages (url?) need to go after.